# Does EWOULDBLOCK work for sendto()?

Tags: c++, c, networking, sockets, asynchronous

Could someone please tell us if EWOULDBLOCK. works sendto()?
If yes! please give an example ... thanks!
If not, is there anything similar to accept error?

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking. A Google search for sendto and EWOULDBLOCK would imply that it can be returned, yes. Any sending operation on a socket could theoretically run out of send-buffer space, which means the operating system would have to wait until such space became available, hence EWOULDBLOCK is a reasonable value to return for a non-blocking socket.

Comment: thanks  for reply. I am trying to make client and server to communicate in asynchronous mode, although I have a problem with sendto.

Comment: How do you know you have a problem with it? It would be helpful if you stated what exactly is happening.

Comment: If you want really to help, I can share my codes with you ... What I am trying is to make client and server independent from each other. I mean when the client or server calls receive() , it would data available on receive() - as it can be the updated or the backuped (last received) - without waiting for send() . By trying to implement this, I get some problem with sendto()  ... thanks again!

Comment: I think what people need to be able to help is details of the actual problem that you are having with `SendTo()`.